# Print dialog loads very slowly in macOS

Tags: macos, mac, high-sierra, printing

**Model:** MacBook Pro (13", Early 2015, 3.1 GHz)

**OS:** High Sierra (10.13.4)

**Printer:** Canon MF4890dw

**Problem:** Whenever I try to print from an app (Preview, TextEdit, etc.), the dialog takes ten seconds or more to load. This does *not* happen when printing from Chrome, which seems to have its own print dialog. Once the print dialog opens, it functions normally, and printing functions normally.

**Tried so far:**
- Shutting down
- Deleting and re-adding printer  in System Preferences
- Turning printer on and off
- Resetting SMC
- Boot volume first aid/repair

**Any idea what might be going wrong here?**

Comment: Have you tried deleting and recreating the printer in `System Preferences... > Printers and Scanners`?

Comment: Yep, I did try that. It seems to be printer independent. The dialog box is slow to load even when using other printers.

Comment: Just wondering, is this *new* behaviour, or has it always been like this? If it's new, did it coincide with anything else (e.g. new hardware, software update, etc)?

Comment: I've noticed it as new in the past few weeks, but I haven't made any printer or hardware related changes in that time. Obviously *something* changed, but I just have no idea what it would've been.

Comment: I've been seeing this in Monterey, so it obviously isn't fixed!